# How can I verify a Paypal account registered under a business name using GetVerifiedStatus?

Tags: paypal

I am successfully using Paypal's Adaptive Accounts API's [`GetVerifiedStatus`](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-accounts/GetVerifiedStatus_API_Operation/) endpoint to verify our users' Paypal accounts by first name, last name, and email address.  However, a significant fraction of them use Paypal business accounts which don't have a first and last name associated (or else they did provide one and have forgotten it.)

Is there a special way to e.g. enter business name in the "first name" field?  Or do all accounts have a first/last name associated and our users need to look that up?  Thanks!

Update to clarify: I'm aware that setting `matchCriteria` to `NONE` in the request theoretically allows one to perform an email-only search.  However, Paypal enables this on a case by case basis, and we haven't been granted `NONE` status, thus must use `NAME` which per the docs requires first and last.

Answer (score 2):

I've been playing around with this and found a way to make the call without having to  set the option to matchCriteria=NONE. If you make the call by placing the business name twice, both in the first name and last name field, you should be able to get a successful reply from the API.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the API and playing around with the [API explorer](https://devtools-paypal.com/apiexplorer/AdaptiveAccounts), you've got two options.

#### Set `matchCriteria` to `NONE`

In this case sending the first name and last name to the API is optional and the validation will only use the email address.

#### Set `matchCriteria` to `NAME`

In this case sending the first name and last name to the API are required and the validation will use the email address, the first name and last name fields.

You can verify the setting by using the [playground](https://devtools-paypal.com/apiexplorer/AdaptiveAccounts), e.g. using test@example.com and any random names.

In your case I would provide the email address, first name and last name as input fields and set `matchCriteria` to `NONE` and send the request to the API.

Comment: Thanks flashfabrixx.  I'm aware of `matchCriteria=NONE` but as you may have noticed from other SO answers on the subject, Paypal doesn't allow email-only searches for the vast majority of users.  We are using `matchCriteria=NAME` and having the problem I described.  I'll update the question to clarify.

Comment: @EricP Okay, I missed the `The NONE option is available only for certain financial institution` note in the docs, sorry. Seems like there aren't many other options left. Using the address with street and zip code for the `AddressVerify API` seems to be error prune as well.